# Как подсветить кнопки?

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка, нужно чтобы вокруг было свечение, делается, по-моему, с помощью бэкграунда.
Может быть некорректно изъясняюсь, сорри, я только учусь. =(

Comment: Свечения разные бывают. Есть внутреннее, есть внешнее, есть просто осветление картинки, есть осветление градиента... Вам какое нужно?

Answer (score 2):

[CSS - Псевдокласс :hover](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover) [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru) очень хорош для учения!

**UPD:** [[@step](/users/7073/step)](/users/7073/step) если так лень посмотреть пример по ссылке и пошевелить извилиной, то вот:

```
a:lihk
{
    background: #786b59; /* Цвет фона под ссылкой */ 
    color: #ffe; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
}
```

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы они просто светились не при наведении.

Answer (score 1):

Такой эффект достигается в CSS3 путем наложения дополнительных градиентов на кнопку. Удобнее подбирать эффекты для подобных кнопок не вручную, а в различных конструкторах, например: [CSS3 Button Generator](http://css3button.net/).

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не использовать CSS3-свойство `box-shadow` ?
Это дает прекрасный эффект подсветки. Вот применение:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #00C;

//1 параметр - смещение по x
//2 параметр - смещение по y
//3 параметр - размытие
//4 параметр - растяжение тени
//5 параметр - цвет
```